# I can't to parse XML from Betfair site using python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping

I need to get some data from betfair site using python
There is a link i need:
https://www.betfair.com/www/sports/exchange/readonly/v1/bymarket?_ak=nzIFcwyWhrlwYMrh&currencyCode=EUR&locale=ru&marketIds=1.158145690&rollupLimit=10&rollupModel=STAKE&types=MARKET_STATE,MARKET_RATES,MARKET_DESCRIPTION,EVENT,RUNNER_DESCRIPTION,RUNNER_STATE,RUNNER_EXCHANGE_PRICES_BEST,RUNNER_METADATA,MARKET_LICENCE

To solve this problem, i saved opened page as xml-document and i did succesfully parse it with this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

filedata = open('bymarket.xml')

cont = bs(filedata, 'lxml')

course = cont.find('venue')
print(course.text)
container = cont.find('runners')
item = container.find_all('runnernode')
for horse in item:
    runner = horse.find('runnername').text
    odds = horse.find('availabletolay').find('price').text
    print(runner, odds)
```

Using this code, I can get the results I need.
But, when I try to get this data directly from the page nothing happens - 
no items are found and I got None.
Please, help a non-professional get the information I need

Comment: available to lay can have multiple price values - do you only want the first? In your example that would be 4.9 for Kibaar.  You have multiple runners in runner node. Can there only ever be 1 child node of runners?

Comment: Yes. I need the first value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `Accept` header to the request and specify `xml` parser

```
 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
```

Py:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
     'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}
r = requests.get('https://www.betfair.com/www/sports/exchange/readonly/v1/bymarket?_ak=nzIFcwyWhrlwYMrh&currencyCode=EUR&locale=ru&marketIds=1.158145690&rollupLimit=10&rollupModel=STAKE&types=MARKET_STATE,MARKET_RATES,MARKET_DESCRIPTION,EVENT,RUNNER_DESCRIPTION,RUNNER_STATE,RUNNER_EXCHANGE_PRICES_BEST,RUNNER_METADATA,MARKET_LICENCE', headers = headers)
soup = bs(r.content, 'xml')
for horse in soup.select('RunnerNode'):
    name = horse.select_one('runnerName').text
    first_availableToLay_price_size =  horse.select_one('price').text
    print(name, first_availableToLay_price_size)
```

---

Output:

[image]